# R RODBC sqlSave - match by column names

Tags: r, match, rodbc

Very difficult to provide a working example here, so I try to explain the problem.

I have a table in a database `tableDb` with columns `A`, `B`, `C`.

I have a data frame in a R `df` with columns `A`, `C`, `B`.

Now I am using

```
sqlSave(channelToDb, dat = df, tablename = "tableDb", append = TRUE,
rownames = FALSE, fast = FALSE)
```

to save the data from `df` in `tableDb`.

The problem is, that the data from column `B` of `df` is stored in column `C` of `tableDb` and `C` of `df` is stored in column `B`.

So `sqlSave` does not match the two tables by column name, but just by index?

Is there a way to match by column name?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest was to do this is to reorder your data frame before saving:

`df<-df[c("A", "C", "B")]`

this will put the data frame in the same order as the table or you could us a temporary data frame

`df_to_table<-df[c("A", "C", "B")]`

Then

```
sqlSave(channelToDb, dat = df_to_table, tablename = "tableDb", append = TRUE,
rownames = FALSE, fast = FALSE)
```

If you want to keep your enivronment clean and small, then just remove the temporary table after...

`rm(df_to_Table)`

and you are back to your original work space with the original `df` in your environment and your variables saved to your table in the correct order.

Comment: Yes, of course that would be an option and I am currently doing it like that. But my real world table has several more columns and I thought there is a better way to this.

Comment: You could write a function yourself which reads the field names from the database and drops them in as a list in a temp frame and then saves the out. You would just need to give it the database name, the data frame and a file name and it could do it all for you.